# NavigationLink off bottom of screen not activating programmatically

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I have a view where there is a calendar taking up space on the top of the screen. For the sake of this example I've simplified it to some text with a spacer. If you use the button to cause an item to be selected programmatically it will not activate the link until you scroll the list down a little bit. I assume this is because lists are lazy loading? But how can I do this another way that it will work or somehow make the list non-lazy? (There will never be more than a handful of entries in this list so the performance penalty of loading non-visible items shouldn't ever be an issue) The purpose of this is that the user is on an "Add" screen and when they save that I want them to go back to the screen that now has their item in the list, but programmatically bring them to the detail view where it will then do the next step necessary for the item entry.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items : [Item] = [Item(id: 1, name: "item1"), Item(id: 2, name: "item2"), Item(id: 3, name: "item3")]
    
    @State var selectedItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Button {
                    selectedItem = items[0]
                } label: {
                    Text("Select Item")
                }
                
                List{
                    Section{
                        VStack{
                            Text("TEST")
                            Spacer().frame(height: 800)
                            Text("TEST")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section("Section") {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: DestView(item: item),
                                tag: item,
                                selection: $selectedItem
                            ) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text(item.name).font(.headline)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DestView: View {
    
    var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
    }
}

struct Item : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id : Int
    var name : String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I want to propose an answer to my own question however I'm interested in others thoughts on this to see if there is still some better way. I think if I add a second ForEach towards the top with EmptyView() so that the are invisible but able to be activated regardless of scroll position.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var items : [Item] = [Item(id: 1, name: "item1"), Item(id: 2, name: "item2"), Item(id: 3, name: "item3")]
    
    @State var selectedItem: Item?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Button {
                    selectedItem = items[0]
                } label: {
                    Text("Select Item")
                }
                //******* Begin
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: DestView(item: item),
                        tag: item,
                        selection: $selectedItem
                    ) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
                // ******* End
                List{
                    Section{
                        VStack{
                            Text("TEST")
                            Spacer().frame(height: 800)
                            Text("TEST")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Section("Section") {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            NavigationLink(
                                destination: DestView(item: item),
                                tag: item,
                                selection: $selectedItem
                            ) {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text(item.name).font(.headline)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DestView: View {
    
    var item: Item
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.name)
    }
}

struct Item : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id : Int
    var name : String
}
```